# Почему не конкатенируются строки в тернарном выражении?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Не получается конкатенировать строки в тернарном выражении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если active **true**, то он просто занимает всё строку и не добавляет "list_item"

Хотя при проверке это всё строки, не понимаю почему так

Comment: Все правильно. Ваше + 'list_item' относится к else тернарного оператора. Оберните условие в скобки или поменяйте порядок(если допустимо). Замените скрин на код и сможете получить ответ с примерами

Comment: @SwaD Разобрался, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: Такую логику присвоения классов лучше писать в JS как предложил @ksa, так как это практичнее и читабельнее.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю заменить твою конструкцию с тернарками на такую

```
const cls = ['list_item']
if (el.isSelected) cls.push('active')
else if (el.isOut) cls.push('out')
className={cls.join(' ')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Переписал с перестановкой и добавлением скобок

```
className={"list_item " + (el.isSelected ? " active " : (el.isOut ? " out " : " "))}
```